# How to use unpkg with private repositories?

Tags: npm, nexus3, unpkg

Is there a way of doing something similar to unpkg for private npm repositories?  I am specifically using sonatype nexus.

The closest thing I can think of is to do an npm build and publish the JS files in some web server somewhere and include it using `<script ...>`

Answer (score 0):

There is not a feature inside NXRM for doing this. Your suggestion of doing a build and then publishing the JS files might work and you could use a raw-hosted repository for it.